# Sitecore User Group Jaipur Meeting March 18th 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We’re happy to announce second Sitecore user group Jaipur meetup on Saturday, March 18th, 2017 from 2.00 PM – 6.00 pm IST.

Venue - [Unicolumn Software Pvt.Ltd.](https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/''/unicolumn/@26.9118113,75.7402737,16.25z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x396db49e16bd5b21:0xb98d27e2a7b5171a!2m2!1d75.741785!2d26.9122376) Vaishali nagar, Jaipur

The line-up is:

• **Sitecore Azure** - Sitecore Azure Basics and how to deploy Sitecore solution in cloud usind Azure Pass.
By: **Jagmohan Singh Rathore (Sitecore MVP,2016-2017)**

• **Unit test your Sitecore website with Fake DB** 
- Unit testing is crucial for agile software development so let's get hands dirty with it for a sitecore website. By : **Vipin Banka**

Agenda -

- 2:00pm IST (8:30am UTC) - Welcome/Registration
- 2:30pm IST (9:00am UTC) - First Presentation
- 4:00pm IST (10:30am UTC) - Snacks and Tea
- 4:30pm IST (11:00am UTC) - Second Presentation

We’re really looking forward to seeing you on the 18th, and again, don’t forget to RSVP!

If you have any questions. Please contact us -

Email - sitecoreugjaipur@gmail.com

Mahendra - +91 92525 82898

Gaurav - +91 80581 54358

Office - 0141-2358028

Meetup - [Click Here](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Jaipur-Meetup/events/237578804/)

Website - [sugjaipur.com](http://sugjaipur.com)

Regards

SUGJPR

Comment: Please include scheduled times in UTC and the names of the speakers. Thank you!

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion began Mar 8 at 8:30